# Tool to Preview Photoshop Brush Set (Windows 7/10)

Tags: asset-management, photoshop

Is there a tool to preview Photoshop brush sets for Windows 7/10? (.abr files.) Google search gave me a few choices for Mac only.

Answer (score 2):

Photo Brush is suitable for all Windows PC's. System requirements: Microsoft® Windows® 7, Vista or XP (32-bit or 64-bit editions; 1 GHz processor or better; 2 GB of RAM; 1 GB of free disk space; minimum screen resolution: 1024 x 768 (highly recommended higher resolution).